# Keymaps working on tty but not on Gnome - Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard

When I was at Zsh installing Arch Linux, I listed the keymaps `ls /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/**/*.map.gz` and selected the one for my keyboard `loadkeys br-abnt2.map.gz` and worked fine there.

After the installing is complete and I `startx`'d the OS for the first time, I noticed that my keys was unset again. So I ran `loadkeys ...` again but got an error message that couldn`t find file or something. Then I went there to check and indeed a lot of the folders inside /kbd/keymaps was not added after the installation even after setting the locale correctly.

Then, I searched on the internet and downloaded `br-abnt2.kmap.gz` (.kmap not .map because I didn't find a .map file for it, I think this won't make difference). Now I'm running `loadkeys` and having no output but I still can't type using my standard format. I added the kmap.gz to the `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps` directory already.

So, the question is, how to add new keymaps to system in order to load them correctly? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Just found out that the problem is happening only in gnome interface. If I restart and get in `tty` the fonts are displayed normally and my keyboard keys are according to my language.

Comment: `man localectl`!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were looking at this: [KEYMAP (Português)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KEYMAP_%28Portugu%C3%AAs%29)

The "tty" (Linux console) keymaps and fonts are separate from GNOME.  For that (running in X), this page may help for a start: [Can't configure correct keymap for my language](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=67044)

However, the system settings in GNOME are the best place to look, e.g., as in *[How to change system language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language)*